# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method, after wrapped in int type, results in blank

Tags: python

```
  File "load.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "load.py", line 108, in main
    create_text_file(new_path, './', 0.85)
  File "load.py", line 84, in create_text_file
    X_train = images[0:len(images) * percentage]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Trying to convert images to `train.txt` and `val.txt`. but it is giving above error.

I tried to solve the error by writing this line `X_train = images[0:len(images) * int(percentage)]`, but then X_train value becomes empty. Can anyone please help ?

> Code snippet

```
    X_train = images[0:int(len(images)) * int(percentage)]
    X_test = images[len(images) * int(percentage):]
```

Error is on line 1, line 2 works perfect.

Comment: What is the value of `percentage`?

Comment: @rdas its float 0.85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a decimal/float percentage that's why `X_train` is empty.
See this example:

```
In [2]: int(.6667)
Out[2]: 0
```

You can instead multiply the length of images by the percentage then turn that to an integer:

```
In [8]: l = [1,2,3]

In [9]: l[:int(len([l) * 0.75)]
Out[9]: [1, 2]

In [10]: l[int(len(l) * 0.75):]
Out[10]: [3]
```

For your example:

```
X_train = images[:int(len(images) * percentage)]
```